# Extracting referenced Twitter usernames from Tweet in R

Tags: r, regex, twitter

I am currently trying to get a list of all referenced Twitter profiles in a database of Tweets in R. I already segmented each Tweet into a list of words (as string) and now I want to look up each value, that starts with "@" and save it (or the list if there is multiple references) into a new column of the database.

Data Sample:

```
@medieninsider Was meinen Sie, woher der zitierte Ausschnitt stammt?  Die Angabe der Quelle habe ich mir gespart, sie nennt sich in 6 Sätzen ja selbst 3 Mal.  P.S.: 17 € pro Monat für eine Website und paar SPAM-Mails - da gibt es für 18,36 € aber DEUTLICH mehr und vielfältigeres beim ÖRR.
```

With the function `strsplit()` I was able to generate the following list out of this string:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "@medieninsider" "Was"            "meinen"         "Sie,"          
 [5] "woher"          "der"            "zitierte"       "Ausschnitt"    
 [9] "stammt?"        ""             "Die"            "Angabe"        
[13] "der"            "Quelle"         "habe"           "ich"           
[17] "mir"            "gespart,"       "sie"            "nennt"         
[21] "sich"           "in"             "6"              "Sätzen"        
[25] "ja"             "selbst"         "3"              "Mal."          
[29] ""             "P.S.:"          "17"             "€"             
[33] "pro"            "Monat"          "für"            "eine"          
[37] "Website"        "und"            "paar"           "SPAM-Mails"    
[41] "-"              "da"             "gibt"           "es"            
[45] "für"            "18,36"          "€"              "aber"          
[49] "DEUTLICH"       "mehr"           "und"            "vielfältigeres"
[53] "beim"           "ÖRR."
```

How can I extract the Twitter profile (with the "@" as prefix) as a new variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub`

```
string <- "@medieninsider Was meinen Sie, woher der zitierte Ausschnitt stammt?  Die Angabe der Quelle habe ich mir gespart, sie nennt sich in 6 Sätzen ja selbst 3 Mal.  P.S.: 17 € pro Monat für eine Website und paar SPAM-Mails - da gibt es für 18,36 € aber DEUTLICH mehr und vielfältigeres beim ÖRR."

sub("(@\\w+)\\s+.*", "\\1", string)
[1] "@medieninsider
```

Another option is using `str_extract_all` if you have a vector consisting of several tweets

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string, "(@\\w+)")
[[1]]
[1] "@medieninsider"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. with "st_extract_all" it also identified sentence notations (".", ",", etc.), so for posts with multiple references this was the best option to use!

Answer (score 2):

Use str_detect from stringr

consider that the list generated is vec, then use vec

```r
index <- which(str_detect(vec,'@'))
vec[index]
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. But with the solution from Jilber Urbina I didn't need to take the step in between to create a vector of the string. So that solved my problem but your answer also solves my request :)